# How can I a group jQuery AJAX queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization, grouping

I have some code that looks like this (I left out the parts that are unimportant for the question):

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url:  "prepXML.php",  
    data: "method=getartists&user=" + userName + "&amount=" + amount,  
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) { 
        $("artist", xml).each(function(){
            // calculate and output some stuff and then call getTracks()
            getTracks(artistName, artistNamePOST, artistPlaycount, divId, artistId);
        }); 
    }
});  

function getTracks(artistName, artistNamePost, artistPlaycount, divId, artistId){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url:  "prepXML.php",  
        data: "method=gettracks&user=" + userName + "&artist=" + artistNamePOST + "&playcount=" + artistPlaycount,  
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            // calculate and output some stuff
        });                     
    }
});
```

When this is run, it calls getTracks() fifty times and makes quite some (server) CPU load in very short time until it all gets done. What I would like to do is to group AJAX getTrack() queries by for example 5 at a time, wait until those five are done, then call the next five, wait until the next five are done, call the next five etc. The purpose of this would be to make fewer queries at basically the same time (less and more evenly spread CPU load).

I am unsure how or even if this can be done since it kind of partially beats the point of AJAX, but I would still like to make this work if possible. Could someone please point me into the right direction? Thank you.

To better understand what I need this for and what the app does, here is a link to the [**app**](http://lastfm.cmikavac.net/). it can be tried out with any lastfm nick (if you don't have one, you can use mine - "pootzko"). I hope I am allowed to put the link in the post(?), if not, feel free to remove it..

Comment: Why don't you just return an array of tracks along with your artist data when you do `method=getartist` then you only need to do one server call (per artist). maybe have a method called `getartistwithtracks`

Comment: @musefan - this works with lastfm api where getartists first queries lastfm and gets a list of top listened arists, after which it has to make new separate queries against lastfm to get information about tracks for each of these artists.

Comment: Look at this one: [bunch of ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425885/trying-to-make-2-ajax-calls-via-jquery-and-then-prepending-the-data-taken-from/42426722#42426722)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider only retrieving track info for artists that a user has clicked on. Or possibly retrieving *all* of the data via a single request (perhaps then after it is retrieved process it in batches via `setTimeout()`).

But something along the lines of the following might work to do only five requests at a time:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url:  "prepXML.php",  
    data: "method=getartists&user=" + userName + "&amount=" + amount,  
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) { 
      var artists = $("artist", xml),
          i = 0,
          c = 0;

      function getTracksComplete() {
         if (--c === 0)
            nextBatch();
      }

      function nextBatch() {
         for(; c < 5 && i < artists.length; i++, c++) {
            // artists[i] is the current artist record    
            // calculate and output some stuff and then call getTracks()
            getTracks(artistName, artistNamePOST, artistPlaycount, divId, artistId,
                      getTracksComplete); 
         }
      }

      // Optional - if you need to calculate statistics on all the artists
      // then do that here before starting the batches of getTracks calls
      artists.each(function() { /* do something */ });

      // Kick of the first batch of 5
      nextBatch();
   } 
});

function getTracks(artistName, artistNamePost, artistPlaycount, divId, artistId,
                   callback){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url:  "prepXML.php",  
        data: "method=gettracks&user=" + userName + "&artist=" + artistNamePOST + "&playcount=" + artistPlaycount,  
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            // calculate and output some stuff
        },
        complete : function() {
            if (callback) callback();
        });                     
    }
});
```

The above was just off the top of my head (so I didn't have time to build it to scale or to paint it), but the idea is that instead of using `.each()` to loop through all of the artists at once we will cache the jQuery object and do a few at a time. Calling the function `nextBatch()` (which is local to the success handler and thus has access to the local variables) will run a loop that calls `getTracks()` only 5 times, but starting processing from where we left off the previous time. Meanwhile `getTracks()` has been updated slightly to accept a callback function so when *its* ajax call completes (and note we do this on complete rather than success in case of errors) it can let the main process know that it has finished. Within the callback we keep track of how many have completed and when they all have call `nextBatch()` again.

Answer (score 1):

Either include all the track information in the data that is returned from `getartists` OR only call `getTracks` when someone wants to see the tracks for a specific Artist.

e.g.

Display all the Artists, and have a "View Tracks" options. Only once this is clicked then you get the tracks.

To me this is the best option because if you are loading up ALL the tracks for ALL the artists, then there is a lot of data that that probably isnt needed. No one is going to want to look through all the artists and all the artists tracks (unless the specifically want to).

Comment: the thing is that actually all the data is used to calculate some statistics.

Comment: If it is just being used to calculate statistics and then display the stats, then wouldnt it be better just to do this all in `getartists` and just return the stats?

Comment: then what happens is that the app "hangs" for 30-40 seconds until it is all calculated so I would say plain ajax is better option than that. I just wanted to "improve" that if possible. I put a link to the app in my original post, to give a better idea of what it does if that helps anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to process all the artist data into the array and then start executing `.ajax()` requests in the batches of 5. When those 5 requests are done, next batch is executed, etc.

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/uvahak/2/edit#javascript,live)** is a working demonstration.

```
// just success changed
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url:  "prepXML.php",  
  data: "method=getartists&user=" + userName + "&amount=" + amount,  
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    var data = [];
    // prepare the data
    $("artist", xml).each(function(){
        data.push({ name: artistName /** rest of data */ } );
    }); 
    // start processing the data
    processData(data, 0);
  }
});  

// process the data by sending requests starting from index
function process(data, index) {
  var xhrs = [];
  for (var i = index; i < index + 5 && i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(data) {
       xhrs.push($.ajax({  
         type: "POST",  
         url:  "prepXML.php",  
         data: "method=gettracks&user=" + data.name /** rest of the data */  
         dataType: "xml",
         success: function(xml) {
           // calculate and output some stuff
         }
       }));
     })(data[i]);
   }

  // when current xhrs are finished, start next batch
  $.when.apply(this, xhrs).then(function() { 
    index += 5; 
    if (index < data.length) {
      process(data, index); 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution/idea. I chose @nnnnnn's solution because to me it was easier to understand and implement. thanks for the effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to clearly understand the logic of you application, but I think a better way should be collecting previously all the data you need to send (50 entries in a JSON object) and then call getTracks function only once, passing only one JSON object.